# Rewriting URLs in PHP instead of server config

Tags: php, routes, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a very lightweight routing framework (to go with [php-skel](http://github.com/ngspinners/php-skel)).

The first thing I'd like to investigate is specifying rewrite rules in a php file ("not found" handler) in a similar way to how this is specified in the server configs.

Here's a potential example (but I'm wanting to know what frameworks provide something this lightweight):

File route.php:

```
route('application/api', '/api/index.php');
route('application', '/application/index.php');
```

File appplication/index.php:

```
route(':module/:action', function($module, $action) {
    include(__DIR__ . '/' . $module . '/' . $action . '.php');
});
```

What are the lightweight routing frameworks / functions or techniques?

Answer (score 2):

The php way:

`http://example.com/index.php/controller/action/variables`

```
$routing = explode("/" ,$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$controller = $routing[1];
$action = $routing[2];
$variables = $routing[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [parse url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function that could be easily used to route.
You can then call explode() on the path portion that is returned to get an array of the url components.

Answer (score -2):

PHP can't rewrite URLs the way mod_rewrite can, it can only redirect to other pages, which'd basically double the number of hits on your server (1 hit on php script, 2nd hit on redirect target).

However, you can have the PHP script dynamically load up the "redirect" pages' contents:

```
switch($_GET['page']) {
    case 1:
        include('page1.php');
        break;
    case 2:
        include('page2.php');
        break;
    default:
        include('page1.php');
}
```

this'd be pretty much transparent to the user, and you get basically the same effect as mod_rewrite. With appropriate query and path_info parameters, you can duplicate a mod_write "pretty" url fairly well.