# Url rewriting mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with mod_rewrite for the first time. 
I am going to present a scenario. Just let me know whether it's possible or not.

suppose I have a database table with three attributes table(id,title,parentid).

and my url to access the particular content looks like this:

```
example.com/content.php?id=some_value
```

Now, for some_value id , title is some_title. Is it possible that such that

```
example.com/some_title/
```

can be renamed to above url.OR

```
example.com/content.php?id=some_value&title=some_title
```

I may also have url such as :

```
example.com/content.php?id=some_value&title=some_title&parenttitle=parent_title
```

In which case entered url should be something like this:

```
example.com/parent_title/some_title/
```

If I haven't made myself clear do let me know. Again this is my first attempt at mod_rewrite. So even a small information will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can put in your .htaccess file

```
  # /id - search an ID
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(/?)$ /content.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]                                                                   

  # /title - search a title
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\ ]+)$ /content.php?title=$1 [NC,QSA,L]                                                          

  # /parent/child - search parent and child
  RewriteRule ^([a-z\-\ ]+)/([a-z0-9\-\ ]+)$ /content.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [NC,QSA,L]                                   

  # /id/name - search id and title
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-\ ]+)$ /content.php?id=$1&child=$2 [NC,QSA,L]                                           

  # /search/some_title - search for a title
  RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9\-\ ]+)(/?)$ /search.php?q=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

etc...

Comment: I guess it is possible after all!

Answer (score -1):

NO! URL rewriting DO NOT generate anything JUST change things you have to something else! you should put id,title or parentid in URL if you're going to use them!

Comment: thanks.. that what I thought . Is there any php alternative available??

Comment: @akashr sure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196698/rewriting-urls-in-php-instead-of-server-config/7199782#7199782)

Comment: @akashr why you don't put id and parent id in URL? I think you can get your data by title(if it's unique)

Comment: @Death add me in yahoo HeXa_bit@