# How can I redirect all address bar requests to one index page? And use a requested subfolder as input

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am using PHP, Ajax, JS, and HTML and after many searches, I am per-google-plexed.

How can I take a user visiting www.foo.com/bar to www.foo.com/index.php and use *bar* as input?

I want to avoid creating a folder for each possible value.

I would like to keep /bar in the address bar

Comment: you will need to use mod-rewrite, assuming your using apache.

Comment: This is a server-side question, right?  Your server has to serve up some page when given www.foo.com/bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Apache mod_rewrite here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542913/how-to-allow-three-optional-parameters-in-the-url-by-htaccess/7380631#7380631) or [using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196698/rewriting-urls-in-php-instead-of-server-config/7199782#7199782) but with uri like this:

`http://example.com/index.php/controller/action/variables`

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into [mod_rewrite](http://www.modrewrite.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the location and change to whatever you want via javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// var x = ( cut out part of the current location )
// Then replace with whatever:
location.replace('http://www.example.com/');
</script>
```

Examples:

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/javascript-redirect-scripts/

http://www.javascriptredirect.com/timed.htm

---

**Also, here is a php alternative to mod_rewrite (which is what you should be using instead but if you cant, there are other ways):**

[php alternative to mod_rewrite](http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/php-alternative-to-mod-rewrite-for-se-friendly-urls)

Comment: Guess you missed the line: "I want to avoid creating a folder for each possible value." which your solution would require.

Comment: @epasc I am assuming he cant use mod_rewrite, since his question indicates only using php/js/html/ajax, so these are the best alternatives for someone who cant use mod_rewrite.